# Show window in Electron without taking focus?

Tags: electron

I'm trying to make notifications like Google Chrome's in Electron. I've tried setting `focusable: false` but the window still takes focus on `window.show()`

I also tried setting `show: true` and avoiding calling `window.show()` but get the same effects.

I've done quite a bit of research and I can't find anything on this. Is there no way to do this besides asking the developers to implement such a feature? Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`window.show()` will always focus the new Window, you have to use `window.showInactive()` in order [to open a window that is not focused.](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md#winshowinactive)

Comment: Thanks very much. That's helpful. I'm not sure what you mean regarding notifications though. It's not really useful on Windows 7 is my impression. You can only do notification balloons, right?

Comment: @Slapbox i removed the tray stuff from the answer, i just confused something when reading your question ;)

Comment: Thanks very much Hans. Once I have a chance to try this solution out if it works I will mark this answer accepted.

Comment: A bit late, but I kept my word!